# Acceptable method for calling View.invalidate on a repeating timer

Tags: java, android, timer

I'm planning to have UI elements in constant movement in a View.  I'm thinking the best way is to just have a Timer running in the View and calling a method for updating the state of my objects and calling invalidate.

What are the best objects to do this with (Timer, TimerTask, Handler) and what are the best performing ways to do it.  Are there any pitfalls I need to avoid for performance?

Also, what is an acceptable amount of time between iterations?  Is there a standard, or does it depend on the complexity and amount of objects being drawn?

Answer (score 3):

If you are updating UI Elements, better use View's `postDelayed()` or `postInvalidateDelayed()` methods. They guaranteed it will be scheduled in UI thread and redraw.

Iteration isn't too matters. I once made a 'stop-watch' timer that running like 40+ fps and still the UI is responsive enough. Notice that whatever runnable you placed in postDelay will be running on UI's thread, so, if you need to do some heavy drawing, I would prepare (in second thread) it in a separate Bitmap and just post the bitmap whenever the drawing is completed (double buffering technique)

=Update=
What I previously done is, I need to draw something on a view, which the whole drawing take about 200ms to complete. The way I do is like this (suppose the run is in a separate thread other than UI thread):

```
Bitmap result;
void run(){
    while(running){
        result = doTheHeavyWeightDrawing();
        post(new Runnable(){
            setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(...));
        });
        try{
            sleep(100);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){ return; }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, for repeated tasks you'd call postDelayed from the View to start the loop and then in the Runnable that gets executed call postDelayed again to continue the loop?

Comment: @Rich, I updated my answer, to something similar to what I did before, except I use post instead of delay. Remember, whatever running in `postDelayed` will be executed in the View Thread, and that will stall the performance of the User Interface. Try to do as little as possible in the View Thread would be the best.